# Grab key/value pair from Array of NSDictionaries

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

My situation: I have an NSArray of NSDictionaries. The NSDictionary has 2 key/value pairs and I want to just want one of the key/value pairs.

I want grab the key/value pair at index 0:

[image]

What is the best method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary has no concept of the order of the keys. You would need to use another type of collection class like Matt Gallagher's [OrderedDictionary](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html)